# Unable to directly paste a link from Twitter into web forms in Mobile Safari

Tags: ios

When I copy a `t.co` link (**tap/hold** > `Copy link`) from the Twitter app, I am unable to paste into **any** web forms in Mobile Safari. I can still paste into other objects (e.g. the address bar, the search bar, the Notes app, etc).

Is this a bug? How can I avoid having to first paste the link and then recopy (`Select All > Copy`) it as @iglvzx suggests in the comments?

Comment: Which web page? Which form? Most likely, this is a problem with the web page itself, rather than iOS or Twitter.

Comment: I try to paste the link on the search form on http://www.google.com

Comment: Strange. I can confirm this. I workaround is to paste it somewhere else and then `Select All > Copy`. Then you can paste it into Google. Edit: I stand corrected, there is something definitely going wrong here. Perhaps something with the way Twitter saves to the clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I closed Twitter out and re-opened, then I was able to paste again.